# Hystrix circuit breaker consecutive fails

Tags: hystrix, circuit-breaker

Is there a way to configure trip the circuit breaker after X consecutive fails without having to implement it myself?

All I could find it about percentage of fails in a certain time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to set following configuration for command.

```
hystrix.command.default.circuitBreaker.requestVolumeThreshold
```

Please checkout the following link for more details

https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/Configuration#circuitBreaker.requestVolumeThreshold

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38524259/hystrix-configuration/38525660 for what `requestVolumeThreshold` does.  Hystrix does not offer a circuit-breaker which breaks after X consecutive fails.