# hystrix volume threshold config

Tags: config, hystrix, circuit-breaker

default_circuitBreakerRequestVolumeThreshold=20 does default config in hystrix mean only 20 requests are allowed in 10 sec interval with 1 second bucket? 
Eg: If there are more than 2 requests every second in last 10 seconds does hsytrix open the circuit?

Comment: Close duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38524259/hystrix-configuration/38525660#38525660

Comment: that was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you @mountain-traveller